# error while running this command crf_learn template train model?

Tags: crf++

$ crf_learn template_file train_file model_file
CRF++: Yet Another CRF Tool Kit
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Taku Kudo, All rights reserved.

encoder.cpp(340) [feature_index.open(templfile, trainfile)] feature_index.cpp(135) [ifs] open faile

templete and train file is in my CFR++ folder

Comment: please explain more about your problem?

Comment: i am following this link (https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) and i am facing a problem regarding this command crf_learn template_file train_file model_file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have permission to access the file.
Or check the path of the file.